# Flask mysqldb Python DELETE table entry

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

I'm having an issue trying to delete data from the database. I can't find any issues with my code for deletions. Inserting data works perfectly fine, but deleting data is failing me. Here is my route which shows both inserting and deleting data.

```
@app.route('/our-ma/addsite', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addsite():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    sites = cur.execute('Select * from site_info')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    form = Edit_Delete()
    addForm = SiteInfo()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            mycur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            # print("This is the site to delete:", form.site.data)
            sql = f"""delete from site_info where site_name="{{form.site.data}}"; """
            mycur.execute(sql)
            mycur.connection.commit()
            sites = mycur.execute('select * from site_info')
            data = mycur.fetchall()
            for x in data:
                print(x)
            mycur.close()
            return render_template('add_site.html', title='Add Site', data=data, form = form, addForm=addForm)


        if addForm.validate_on_submit():
            print("This addsite form is being called right now.")
            specialnotes = request.form['specialnotes']
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO site_info (`site_contact`, `contact_num`, `site_name`, `printer_count`, `terminal_count`, `cd_count`, `contract_status`, `special_notes`) values ("{addForm.contact.data}", "{addForm.contactnum.data}", "{addForm.sitename.data}", "{addForm.printercount.data}", "{addForm.termcount.data}", "{addForm.cdcount.data}", "{addForm.contractstatus.data}", "{specialnotes}"); """)
            cur.connection.commit()
            x = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM site_info')
            data = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
            return render_template('add_site.html', title='Add site', data=data, form=form, addForm=addForm)

    return render_template('add_site.html', title='Add Site', data=data, form = form, addForm=addForm)
```

Comment: Why are you using double brackets in the delete statement?

Comment: @smallpants yeah I feel like an idiot. I was confusing it with my jinja for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format syntax is off:

`...site_name="{{form.site.data}}";...`

Should be

`...site_name="{form.site.data}";...`